# Internet Explorer Placeholder For Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My application is in need of placeholders for a text field and a textarea field. I know Internet Explorer doesn't support placeholders. I was looking around and I found some fallback code which is working great only for the text field. How can I get this working for the textarea also.

Code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
});

$(function() {
    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $('input[type=text], textarea').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        });
        $('input[type="text"], textarea').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
                <li>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="To:" id="to" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea placeholder="Message:" id="body" rows="10" cols="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                </li>
```

Comment: NITPICK: Do not use placeholder as a [label replacement](http://www.shiftedbits.net/rambling/why-html-placeholders-dont-replace-html-labels/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `$(':text')` to `$('input[type="text"], textarea')`

Alternatively, this existing jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

works on textareas and many types of input fields, including password fields

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        });
        $('input[type="text"], textarea').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is using a [text selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/), change it to also use textarea.

```
$(':text')
```

should be

```
$(':text, textarea')
```

or for [better performance](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/#notes-0) use

```
$('input[type=text], textarea')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would need to replace `:text` with `:text,textarea`.